# XPath Expression in VB.Net - How to search xml document that contains unicode characters

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, xpath

I am trying to construct an xpath expression that searches for the specific text located within the `[CDATA]` tags below, and returns it (note: their will be many `<Car>` nodes, all with unique `[CDATA]` text):

```
<Cars>
    <Car>
        <Value><![CDATA[Login]]></Value>
        <DifValue code="01"><![CDATA[Entrada al sistema]]></DifValue>
        <DifValue code="02"><![CDATA[ĐĂNG NHẬP]]></DifValue>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        .
        .
        .
    </car>
</Cars>
```

The problem is my expression works fine for every `[CDATA]` text except the unicode "ĐĂNG NHẬP" (I just get Nothing returned in "targetText")

Here is a simplified snippet of what I have so far:

```
Dim unicodeText as String = "ĐĂNG NHẬP"

unicodeText = unicodeText.ToLower()

Dim targetText as XmlNode = root.SelectSingleNode("//Cars/*/text()[translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') =""" + unicodeText + """]", namespaceManager)
```

Any thoughts?

**Update**:

Although JLRishe did have a great solution (and I accepted his solution as the answer), I did come up with my own method using RegEx (might not be the best but I'm just sharing):

```
Dim unicodeText as String = "ĐĂNG NHẬP"

unicodeText = unicodeText.ToLower();

Dim targetText as XmlNode = root.SelectSingleNode("//Car/text()[translate(., """ & unicodeText.ToUpper() & """, """ & unicodeText & """) =""" & unicodeText & """]", namespaceManager)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem with your XPath is that it would only find `Car` elements with the value you are looking for, not `DifValue` elements, because `Car`s are the only children of the `Cars` element.

But even if you fix that, it still won't work because that `translate()` approach only works for the 26 characters a-z, not characters with accents (unless you list the upper and lowercase versions of *every* character you need to be able to handle).

In this case, I'd suggest using Linq-to-Xml (i.e. the `XDocument` and `XElement` classes), because it will allow you to do the comparisons in .NET code:

(Note: I assume you won't be instantiating `root` with an XML literal, but I'll put it in my example just for completeness)

```
Dim root As XElement =
    <Cars>
        <Car>
            <Value><![CDATA[Login]]></Value>
            <DifValue code="01"><![CDATA[Entrada al sistema]]></DifValue>
            <DifValue code="02"><![CDATA[ĐĂNG NHẬP]]></DifValue>
        </Car>
        <Car>  . . .  </Car>
    </Cars>

Dim unicodeText As String = "đăng nhập"
Dim found As IEnumerable(Of XElement) =
    root.Descendants("Car").
         Elements().
         Where(Function(el) el.Value.Equals(unicodeText, 
                                         StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: you rock. Thank you very much, this is a clean and easy to read approach :)